# new swift 2 project doesn't recognize pods

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I use xcode 7.2 and today I finished a project and wanted to open another one. I made a new project an made pod init + pod install for swiftyJson and Alamofire and try to run it. I got 19 errors that the pod is unrecognized but I can see the pods in the project files. I asked a friend to open the project on his computer and it runs. The old projects run 100% fine.

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you post your Podfile and the errors you are seeing?

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'stam2' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire'

end.  -- the pod install finish witout any errors but when i try to run the project i get 19 error of unrecognize ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your CocoaPods installed version with pod --version. 1.0.0 was released today and may help! I was running into issues with MagicalRecord on the 1.0.0 pre releases yesterday and had to uninstall and then sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0.

Also, [I'm covering some CocoaPods topics here in the near future.](https://brax.tv/lesson/swift-ios-steamreader-cocoapods-cocoapods/)

Comment: tnx for the fast replay. i tried to install the newest version and its still dont work for new project. my old projects works fine. what do you think i should try ?